# Adding Tme Countdown to App Using a Thread

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, timer

I'm trying to add a countdown timer to an existing app. Naturally, I don't want this timer to stall the rest of the application so I wanted to use an asynchronous thread dedicated to the timer. This is my current code and it doesn't even get to the update function (I used print statements to test this), but does print "Got". Also, I'm trying to update a label with the correct time and you can't do that within the thread. The time variable is a class variable. Not sure if this is even the correct approach, any suggestions?

Edit: Running the timer on main queue doesn't work as it interferes with a pan gesture I already have on the app. Also, any proposed solutions to the timing inaccuracies of the Timer Class would also be great.

```
func startTimer() {
    time = 30
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "timer")
    queue.async {
        print("Got")
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}

func update() {
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        if(time >= 0) {
            time -= 1
            timer.text = String(time)
        } else {
            timer.text = "0"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Like rmaddy alludes, you can't schedule timers on background threads without adding runloop to that thread, which is unnecessarily complicated. And if you wanted to schedule timer on background thread, GCD timer would be better. But there's no point in even doing that. Just schedule your timer from the main thread and be done with it. Nothing you've suggested here is complicated enough to "stall" the main thread.

Comment: What happens when the timer fires, in your `update` method? The timer itself shouldn't be a problem, even if a pan gesture is happening, but if your `update` method takes too long to run then that could be a problem.

Comment: @TomHarrington my update function is just supposed to be bring the timer down 1 every second if the timer is above 0, so it shouldn't take too long. Every second when the update function is called, it restarts the view with the original constraints, which is also undesirable. I thought that running the timer in a thread would solve my issue with my images getting displaced, but I guess that's unnecessarily complicated. I'll try a GCD and see if this fixes my problem.